# Convert from string to int (and throw error if unsuccessful)

Tags: go

My apologies if this is a beginner question, but I simply can't seem to find any solution for this. I'm trying to take an argument that can be either a `string` or an `int`, depending on the context, and I need to determine which type, (then convert it to `int` if it is indeed that type.)

Thank you :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://golang.org/pkg/strconv/#Atoi

```
func Atoi

func Atoi(s string) (i int, err error)
Atoi is shorthand for ParseInt(s, 10, 0).
```

This is an update. To clarify, since Atoi accepts string, then trying to pass an `int` will cause a compile time error. If you need a check during runtime, then you can do something like this.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
    "errors"
)

func toInt(data interface{}) (n int, err error) {
    switch t := data.(type) {
    case int:
        return t, nil
    case string:
        return strconv.Atoi(t)
    default:
        return 0, errors.New(fmt.Sprintf("Invalid type received: %T", t))
    }

    panic("unreachable!")
}

func main() {
    var (
        n int
        err error
    )

    n, _ = toInt("1")
    fmt.Println(n)

    n, _ = toInt(2)
    fmt.Println(n)

    n, err = toInt(32.3)
    fmt.Println(err)
}
```

Comment: But this wouldn't allow you to create a function that can accept either a `string` or an `int`, it will only accept a `string`, wouldn't it? You can convert it, so that part of the question is taken care of, but what about the first part?

Comment: This is what I wanted to do; the argument has to be passed as a `string` anyway. If `Atoi` throws an error, then it will be treated as a `string`. Otherwise, it will be treated as an `int`.

Answer (score 7):

For example,

```
package main

import (
    "errors"
    "fmt"
    "strconv"
)

func IntConv(arg interface{}) (int, error) {
    switch x := arg.(type) {
    case int:
        return x, nil
    case string:
        return strconv.Atoi(x)
    }
    return 0, errors.New("IntConv: invalid argument ")
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(IntConv(7))
    fmt.Println(IntConv("42"))
}
```

Comment: Excellent answer; I hadn't realized this could be done. Thank you, as well!

Comment: nice, didn't know you could `return` multivalues with a pass through like that. +1 for "errors" too

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit late to the party, but you could also use `fmt.Sprintf`:

```
import "fmt"

func ConvertToString(x interface{}) string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("%v", x)
}
```

Passing `"%v"` to Sprintf tells it to format it using the best format it knows, which essentially just means "convert x to a string". This is shorter (and perhaps easier to understand) than the other solutions, but has the disadvantage that it'll allow inputs that aren't `ints` or `strings`.